# Search A Single String In MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, search

I am making a private message system and i created a php search page, I am using JQuery to pass a variable from a text field on keyUp to a PHP file called USearch.php or Username Search. Here is my code:

```
<?php
$Connect = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "Data");
$Val = $_POST['Val'];

if($Val)
{
$Search = 'SELECT * FROM Users WHERE ';
$Term = explode(" ", $Val);

foreach($Term as $Key)
{
    $I = 0;
    $I++;
    if($I == 1)
    {
        $Search .= 'Username LIKE "'.$Key.'" LIMIT 0, 10 ';
    }
    else
    {
        $Search .= 'OR Username LIKE "'.$Key.'" LIMIT 0, 10 ';
    }
}

if($Result = $Connect->query($Search))
{
    while($Row = $Result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $User = $Row['Username'];

        $USearch['S'] = $User;
    }
}
}
echo json_encode($USearch);
?>
```

As you can see, my code has no errors, my problem is that i am searching Users in a DB which means i am searching 1 word or string, by using this PHP code, i would have to type in the exact username for the function to return a value. My real intention was to search the string and return all similar usernames according to my input string.

Comment: Use `%` where you want it to be open ended in your SQL. Read: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html  Also, look in to prepared statements, you're currently open for a SQL attack.

Comment: Thanks, It worked! and i will start to use prepared statements now.

Comment: Well, you are wrong about saying your code has no errors. You might want to review your foreach loop. And try adding % between your $key.

Comment: You're welcome!  @josephcaracuel The `foreach` loop will probably only have one iteration, unless usernames can have spaces, which means it probably should be removed and made to be one statement that can then be prepared. But really, there is no need to be rude when answering a question - syntactically, the code is correct and without error.

Comment: The problem with the `foreach` loop is the value `$I` will only ever = 1, so you'll never get to the `else` part of the if the `if` statement - `$I = 0` should be before the `foreach` loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Jon said - you want to use `%` where you want your SQL to have a wild card.

If you want all values where name is like matt you would do

```
WHERE name LIKE '%matt%'
```